# Can not get value when selection is changed in combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i am trying to update the datagrid as soon as the selection is changed from combobox in wpf

```
private void cmbBatchNo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string CmdString = "SELECT Name FROM StudentReg WHERE Course = '" + 
            cmbUndrGradu.Text + "' and Batch_No = '" + cmbBatchNo.Text + "' ";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CmdString, sc);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Employee");
        sda.Fill(dt);
        StdAttendence.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

if i am trying to put message box to show the combobox item name it is showing blank box

Comment: This is prone to SQL Injection.  Use parameterized queries.

Comment: What is up with all the terrible questions on SO lately...maybe I'm just not so busy at work today so I'm noticing it.  The level of the questions is just horrendous.

Comment: like example what but you have not answered me related to my question

Comment: Show us more code about combobox..

Comment: You should probably actually ask a question if you want an answer...

Comment: @JonH Moaning about terrible questions and not providing anything useful to say isn't helpful. Although that said, me moaning about you moaning about terrible questions isn't helpful either.

Comment: That's true enough but the questions still are awful today.

Comment: @JonH if the questions are awful then don't answer stupid replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cmbUndrGradu.SelectedItem.ToString()`.